# Can't find binary file in path

Tags: bash, paths

folks.

I've extracted a tar file with a few binaries into `/usr/local/arm/bin` and setup my path to include this folder.

When I try to run `which`:

```
$ which arm-elf-gcc
/usr/local/arm/bin/arm-elf-gcc
```

Great! But when I try to run the binary:

```
$ arm-elf-gcc
bash: /usr/local/arm/bin/arm-elf-gcc: No such file or directory
```

That doesn't make ANY sense to me. Any idea on why this is happening?

These are the file permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  2 user user  139468 Mar  6  2006 arm-elf-gcc
```

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 so there is no need for installing the `ia32-libs` for running 32 bits binaries.

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /usr/local/arm/bin/arm-elf-gcc`?

Comment: can you execute it with its full path?

Comment: That's not good idea to place such files in `/usr/local/` directory. Other users of the system may be confused. It's better to place it inside `~/bin` and edit your `~/.bashrc` file to include that path.

Comment: The reason for this is something along the lines of the file not being executable on your current system. Are you sure the binary was built for your current architecture? Also, are you on the amd64  architecture or the i386 architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by installing 32 bits architecture support:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```